# How to add specific value in column in in every row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

here i am trying add (EA) in every record for column 1
is it possible to save  value in column 1 like 1.0 Each(EA) followed by 0.0 / 0.001 (EA)...

```
         df_1
        Out[46]: 
                                              0                      1
        0                       Unit of Measure              Each (EA)
        1                            Conversion               1.0 Each
        2                Net/Gross Weight (lbs)            0.0 / 0.001
        3                     Volume (cubic ft)                    0.0
        4  Shipping Dimensions (inch) L x W x H  0.589 x 0.589 x 0.589
        5                                  GTIN                    NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['1'].apply(lambda x:  str(x) + '(EA)' if '(EA)' not in str(x) else x)
```

if the name of column not is a `str` then use:

```
df[1].apply(lambda x:  str(x) + '(EA)' if '(EA)' not in str(x) else x)
```

Comment: hey @lostCode If the first row contain EA then only it EA should be placed on rest of the records

Comment: hey @lostCode if condition doesn't work for this case rest all is working

Comment: what is your output? `else` , leave the cell as it was

Comment: 0                 1
0                       Unit of Measure          Bag (BG)
1                            Conversion        100.0 Each
2                Net/Gross Weight (lbs)       0.0 / 0.001
3                     Volume (cubic ft)              0.01
4  Shipping Dimensions (inch) L x W x H  4.0 x 3.5 x 1.25
5                                  GTIN    10888277689268                                                                           as this contain BG but still it paste EA

Comment: So you want to add EA to those cells where there is no label ?, since if there is BG also add EA. tea. have I understood correctly?

Comment: if there is (EA) then only EA if there is (BG) then  BG should  be placed

Comment: `if (('(EA)' not in str(x)) and ('(BG)' not in str(x)))`

Comment: hey @lostCode df_2[1].apply(lambda x:  str(x) + '(EA or BG)' if (('(EA)' not in str(x)) and ('(BG)' not in str(x))) else x) if i use this print EA only where it found BG or EA

Comment: `df_2[1].apply(lambda x: str(x) + '(EA)' if (('(EA)' not in str(x)) and ('(BG)' not in str(x))) else x).apply(lambda x: str(x) + '(BG)' if (('(EA)' not in str(x)) and ('(BG)' not in str(x))) else x)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['1']=df['1']+ '(EA)'
```

It will add (EA) to every row except for the row that has `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

```
df_1['1'] = df_1['1'] + " (EA)"
```